commonjs--resolver - Failed to resolve entry for package "crypto"
I'm trying to use webtorrent inside my vue chrome extensione. After installation of the package using pnpm i webtorrent I import the library in my project but when I try to build the project I will get this error in console
vite v5.4.10 building for production...
[plugin:vite:resolve] [plugin vite:resolve] Module "dgram" has been externalized for browser compatibility, imported by "/Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/k-rpc-socket@1.11.1/node_modules/k-rpc-socket/index.js". See https://vite.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.
[plugin:vite:resolve] [plugin vite:resolve] Module "net" has been externalized for browser compatibility, imported by "/Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/k-rpc-socket@1.11.1/node_modules/k-rpc-socket/index.js". See https://vite.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.
[plugin:vite:resolve] [plugin vite:resolve] Module "dns" has been externalized for browser compatibility, imported by "/Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/k-rpc-socket@1.11.1/node_modules/k-rpc-socket/index.js". See https://vite.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.
✓ 250 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 1.43s
error during build:
[commonjs--resolver] Failed to resolve entry for package "crypto". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
    at packageEntryFailure (file:///Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.10_@types+node@22.7.8_sass@1.80.3_terser@5.36.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BWSbWtLw.js:46637:15)
    at resolvePackageEntry (file:///Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.10_@types+node@22.7.8_sass@1.80.3_terser@5.36.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BWSbWtLw.js:46634:3)
    at tryNodeResolve (file:///Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.10_@types+node@22.7.8_sass@1.80.3_terser@5.36.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BWSbWtLw.js:46450:16)
    at Object.resolveId (file:///Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.10_@types+node@22.7.8_sass@1.80.3_terser@5.36.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BWSbWtLw.js:46200:19)
    at file:///Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.21.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19913:40
    at async PluginDriver.hookFirstAndGetPlugin (file:///Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.21.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19813:28)
    at async resolveId (file:///Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.21.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18487:26)
    at async ModuleLoader.resolveId (file:///Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.21.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18890:15)
    at async Object.resolveId (file:///Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.10_@types+node@22.7.8_sass@1.80.3_terser@5.36.0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BWSbWtLw.js:12833:10)
    at async PluginDriver.hookFirstAndGetPlugin (file:///Users/m/Sites/blay/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.21.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19813:28)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1. 

This is the code I have in my vue script tag
//Import the library
import WebTorrent from 'webtorrent';
//Instantiate the library
const client = new WebTorrent();

Is there something I can do to fix this. I've looked at the node_modules folder but I'm unable to find any crypto folder.

This means that you're trying to use a package that's intended for node in a browser, which you cannot do. Considering that the package is designed for both, this means that you imported the wrong entry point that's intended for node. The docs explain this https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent?tab=readme-ov-file#webpack

@EstusFlask so I need to import another version of the library to build it with vite right?

Yes, import it from .min file it suggests, or you'll have to configure vite in a special way

Ok, thank you for the help. I've imported the compiled version and now seems working ok. But it will be nice to see what vite configuration is needed to use the non compiled version of the library

I'd honestly expect vite to pick up this config from the package https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent/blob/master/package.json#L11-L24 by default, so this wouldn't need any extra config, but this depends on how your own project is configured. One of possible fixes would be to polyfill "fs",  "crypto", etc in your project

@EstusFlask ok, thank you.
